# Find a function $f(x)$ with some restrictions...

Tags: calculus

How to find a function $f(x)$ such that the derivative of $F(x)$ is $f(x)$ and $f(x)$ is not continuous in $[a,b]$. For the meaning of *Riemann Integral* $\int f(x) \neq F(b)-F(a)$.

Comment: To find a function which fails the integration formula you have, you need a bit more than discontinuity of $f$. If $f$ is merely integrable over $[a,b]$ and  $F'=f$ on $[a,b]$, then your formula holds. The function $F(x)=x^2\cos(1/x^2)$, $x\ne0$, $f(0)=0$ will work (its derivative is unbounded on $[0,1]$.

Comment: But ∫f(x)=F(1)−F(0),as f is not continuous only on 0,it's a limit.

Answer (score 1):

It is a theorem that for any function $F$ which is differentiable on some interval containing $a$ such that $f = F^{\prime}$ is discontinuous at $a$, the limits $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow a^{+}} f(x)$ and $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow a^{-}} f(x)$ cannot *both* exist. See, for example, Theorem 7 of Chapter 11 of Spivak's book *Calculus* followed by Problem 55 of that same chapter.

This suggests we must find some way of getting a function which fails to be continuous in such a way that one or both of these one sided limits fails to exist, and making our function oscillate wildly is a good bet. The function $\sin(1/x)$ is no good as it cannot be made continuous at $0.$ The function $x \sin (1/x)$ is better - it can be made continuous at $0.$ So we try the function $F(x) = x^{2} \sin (1/x)$ for $x \neq 0$ and $F(0) = 0.$ You should be able to show that $F$ is differentiable at $0$ but that $F^{\prime}$ is discontinuous there.